# Как сделать фоновую картинку полупрозрачной?

Tags: css

есть две картинки. На первой кот не засветлен. Вторая является макетом и надо дописать код как на ней. Единственное условие что картинка является фоном а не отдельным элементом.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код выложите.  ..

Comment: https://github.com/StasRomanov/project1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно при помощи небольшого хака с псевдоэлементом

```
div.bg:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128);
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```css
div.bg {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:solid;
}

div.bg:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128);
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">123</div>
```